# Is this a Ubuntu Software Center Bug: Net connection not available

Tags: software-center

Ubuntu Software Center does not recognize my net connection when I connect using wvdial, which I often do (even though Network-Manager works).

Is this a bug? If so, where do I file a bug report for this?

Regards,
Santanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any other application can connect to the Internet and Ubuntu Software Center cannot, then definitely something is wrong with it. Do report this bug, even if the bug is somewhere else (for example: in the wvdial, or in some system's network settings), the developers will help you diagnose this problem and determine the reason. The page where you should report bugs in Ubuntu Software Center is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+filebug

Comment: Linkified for everyone's convenience, this is [bug 863569](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/863569).